# Django - upload_to parameters?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to upload files to dynamically assigned directories depending on what user is retrieved from a MySQL database. The `uploads_to` function accepts only two arguments according to the docs, so I assume I can't inject another variable to complete the returned path string? Code snippets below:

*models.py*

```
def item_uploads_to(instance, filename, userName):
    return '/home/' + userName would go here + '/path/to/uploads/' + filename

class Document2(models.Model):
    docfile2 = models.FileField(upload_to=item_uploads_to)
```

*views.py*

```
 userName = 'python' # this is a test value, working DB query code goes here
 item_uploads_to(instance, filename, userName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it straight away since you cannot pass additional arguments. But you can add user to the instance you're saving so you can get it by doing `instance.user.username` or even `instance.username`.

In your creation code you would have something like this:

```
doc = Document2(random stuff but no docfile2)
doc.username = userName
doc.docfile2 = theFile
doc.save()
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For my puproses I use class with some method for callable and `__init__` method for various arguments, such as:

```py
class UploadTo:
    def __init__(self, folder = None):
        self.folder = folder
    def save_path(self, instance, filename):
        return f"/path/to/{folder}/{filename}"
```

Using:

```py
class Document2(models.Model):
    docfile2 = models.FileField(upload_to=UploadTo(folder=userName).save_path
```

Note: this approach will generate new migration every time you run `makemigrations`. It changes nothing, but creates new migration file. As for me, I manage this in different ways depend of particular case.

The another approach is to define property or method inside the model itself and then get it from `instance`:

```py
class Document2(models.Model):
    docfile2 = models.FileField(upload_to=item_uploads_to)
    @property
    def user_name(self):
        return userName
```

Then this value is reachable from function:

```py
def item_uploads_to(instance, filename):
    return '/home/' + instance.user_name + '/path/to/uploads/' + filename
```